# Navigate Recordset using userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel userform where I want to navigate recordsets.

```
Sub MoveNext()
Dim SaveTime As Date
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

'//Database Location
Const DB_LOCATION = "C:\Users\sagpatil\Documents\Sagar\Backup\Project\Freight Employee Database\FEDB.mdb"

'//Open Database
If db Is Nothing Then
    Set db = DAO.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(DB_LOCATION)
End If

'//Open Table
If rs Is Nothing Then
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM mydb"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("mydb")
End If

If Not rs.EOF Then         
    rs.MoveNext
    With rs
        UserForm1.TXTECN.Value = rs.Fields(ECNNO) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTName.Value = rs.Fields(1) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTDOJ.Value = rs.Fields(2) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTReportingManager.Value = rs.Fields(3) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTDepartment.Value = rs.Fields(4) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTDOB.Value = rs.Fields(5) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTAddress.Value = rs.Fields(6) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTContactNumber.Value = rs.Fields(7) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTEmergency_Contact_Person.Value = rs.Fields(8) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTEmergency_Contact_Number.Value = rs.Fields(9) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTRelationship.Value = rs.Fields(10) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTGrade = rs.Fields(11) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value = rs.Fields(12) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTLan.Value = rs.Fields(13) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTEmail.Value = rs.Fields(14) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value = rs.Fields(15) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTDeskNumber.Value = rs.Fields(16) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTLockerNumber.Value = rs.Fields(17) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value = rs.Fields(18) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value = rs.Fields(19) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.ComboBox7.Value = rs.Fields(20) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.ComboBox8.Value = rs.Fields(21) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTPassportEXPDate.Value = rs.Fields(22) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTBillResource.Value = rs.Fields(23) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = rs.Fields(24) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.ComboBox4.Value = rs.Fields(25) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTResourceStat.Value = rs.Fields(26) & vbNullString
        UserForm1.TXTInactiveComments.Value = rs.Fields(27) & vbNullString
    End With
Else
    rs.MoveFirst
End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Code does not movenext recordset.

Answer (score 0):

You are recreation Rs each time.  Declare  rs at the top of the user form code, so you can reuse it like your function needs and populate rs on form opening.

Also consider that the form population should also be a function, movement should move the recordset on, then call populate form for example.

Comment: Navigate code is on diffrent module and not un userform, will it work in that case